# How do I add parameters to nodejs telegraf.js commands?

Tags: node.js, telegraf.js

I add parameters to my commands and try to get results according to those parameters, for example

/query -name mars

When I write this, I want it to be detected according to the name here, how do I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use telegraf's middleware system. Here is a sample code:

```js
const { Telegraf } = require('telegraf');
const bot = new Telegraf('YOUR_BOT_TOKEN');
bot.command('query', (ctx) => {
  const commandArgs = ctx.message.text.split(' ');
  for (let i = 1; i < commandArgs.length; i++) {
    const arg = commandArgs[i];
    
    if (arg.startsWith('-')) {
      const paramName = arg.substring(1); 
      const paramValue = commandArgs[i + 1] || '';
      switch (paramName) {
        case 'name':
          queryByName(ctx, paramValue);
          break;      
        default:
          ctx.reply(`Unknown parameter: ${paramName}`);
          break;
      }
      
      i++;
    }
  }
});

function queryByName(ctx, name) {
  ctx.reply(`Querying by name: ${name}`);
}
bot.launch();
```